# Saving JSON files onto a S3 bucket

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, aws-lambda, aws-api-gateway

I have a requirement whereby a client will need to send files that will need to saved onto a `S3 bucket`. I will also need to parse the `JSON` and identify them based on certain `key-pair` values in order to save each of them into a specific `folder/sub-folder`.

Essentially I will need to expose the `S3 bucket` as an endpoint. I have read that it is possible to do so in `VPC` (https://docs.aws.amazon.com/vpc/latest/userguide/vpc-endpoints-s3.html).

However, this seems to be only working with `IPV4` and most importantly I am struggling to see how I can have the "filtering logic" to parse and save the files into the correct folder. Ultimately, my question is.

Can I instead use the `API - Gateway + Lambda function` to meet my requirements?

Is there any potential alternative approach to it?

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can expose an S3 bucket for your client, it's possible to setup it such a way that anyone would be able to upload files (of course, you can also setup an appropriate level of authentication).
Then, once an object is placed inside the bucket, S3 can be setup to trigger an AWS Lambda function, which will take that object, parse it and place into correct folder.

Comment: Thank you for this, it looks like an API Gateway would be rather redundant, correct? Will the Lambda function also take care of parsing the JSON file and place it in the right folder, If I have understood correctly? Can you recommend any resource on how to set expose an S3 bucket? I can only the document as posted in the original question.

Comment: yes, I don't see how API gateway helps here.
Lambda can do all the work of parsing and placing the file.
For exposing a bucket please have a look at https://docs.aws.amazon.com/IAM/latest/UserGuide/reference_policies_examples_s3_rw-bucket.html

Comment: Hi, I do not suppose you know how I can validate the files against the expected schema and direct them to an 'ERROR' folder in S3? I guess i can do the validation from within my Lambda function

Comment: This can be a way, it looks like: https://medium.com/a-man-with-no-server/back-end-validation-on-aws-lambda-and-nodejs-ca08a1d07fa0